# Rotate map based on device orientation in Openlayer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, device-orientation

I am writing an application using osm in Openlayers. I'm having trouble adjusting the direction. I determine the direction of the device. Keeping the icon fixed and rotating the map shows the ridiculous places. However, using the device's orientation, it only shows the right place when you rotate the icon. It may be related to the first aspect of the icon, but I couldn't solve the problem. How can I solve this problem?

```js
 var rota_;
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
  url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
    url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
    icon_url = '//cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    }),
    styles = {
      route: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 6, color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
        })
      }),
      icon: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: icon_url
        })
      })
    };
const view = new ol.View({
  center: [10,10],
  zoom: 7,
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
      vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});
const geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
  // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
  trackingOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  },
  projection: view.getProjection(),
});
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
geolocation.setTracking(1);
const iconCar = new ol.Feature({
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500,
  size: [5, 5],
});
const iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0,5, 1],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180426/wye/kisspng-gps-navigation-systems-computer-icons-arrow-transparent-triangle-5ae25abfa4fff1.7727401715247838076759.jpg',
    rotateWithView: "false",
    scale: 0.1,
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
  })
});
iconCar.setStyle(iconStyle);
new ol.layer.Vector({
  map: map,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconCar],
  }),
});
function compassHeading(alpha, beta, gamma) {
  // Convert degrees to radians
  var alphaRad = alpha * (Math.PI / 180);
  var betaRad = beta * (Math.PI / 180);
  var gammaRad = gamma * (Math.PI / 180);

  // Calculate equation components
  var cA = Math.cos(alphaRad);
  var sA = Math.sin(alphaRad);
  var cB = Math.cos(betaRad);
  var sB = Math.sin(betaRad);
  var cG = Math.cos(gammaRad);
  var sG = Math.sin(gammaRad);

  // Calculate A, B, C rotation components
  var rA = - cA * sG - sA * sB * cG;
  var rB = - sA * sG + cA * sB * cG;
  var rC = - cB * cG;

  // Calculate compass heading
  var compassHeading = Math.atan(rA / rB);

  // Convert from half unit circle to whole unit circle
  if(rB < 0) {
    compassHeading += Math.PI;
  }else if(rA < 0) {
    compassHeading += 2 * Math.PI;
  }

  // Convert radians to degrees
  //compassHeading *= 180 / Math.PI;
  return compassHeading;

}
function locate()
{
  const coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
  iconCar.setGeometry(coordinates ? new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
  map.getView().fit(iconCar.getGeometry(),{maxZoom: 16});
}

function handleOrientation(event) {
  absolute = event.absolute;
  alpha    = event.alpha;
  beta     = event.beta;
  gamma    = event.gamma;
  if(isNaN(rota_))
  {
    rota_ = compassHeading(alpha, beta, gamma);
    view.setCenter([boylam,enlem]);
    //iconStyle.getImage().setRotateWithView(1);
    iconStyle.getImage().setRotation(rota_);
  }
  else
  {
    eski_yon = rota_;
    rota_ = compassHeading(alpha, beta, gamma);   
  }
  if(rota_ != null && !isNaN(rota_))
  {
    iconStyle.getImage().setRotateWithView(0);
    map.getView().setRotation(rota_);
  }
}
```

```css
html,body,#map { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; }
#map {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id = "map"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I multiplied the alpha by -1 and fixed the beta at 90 degrees. Problem solved.

```
function compassHeading(alpha, beta, gamma) {
  var alphaRad = -alpha * (Math.PI / 180);
  var betaRad = beta * (Math.PI / 180);
  var gammaRad = gamma * (Math.PI / 180);
  betaRad = 1.5707963268;
  var cA = Math.cos(alphaRad);
  var sA = Math.sin(alphaRad);
  var cB = Math.cos(betaRad);
  var sB = Math.sin(betaRad);
  var cG = Math.cos(gammaRad);
  var sG = Math.sin(gammaRad);

  var rA = - cA * sG - sA * sB * cG;
  var rB = - sA * sG + cA * sB * cG;
  var rC = - cB * cG;

  var compassHeading = Math.atan(rA / rB);

  if(rB < 0) {
    compassHeading += Math.PI;
  }else if(rA < 0) {
    compassHeading += 2 * Math.PI;
  }
  return compassHeading;

}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `return Math.atan2(rA, rB);` instead of adjusting the angle after calling `Math.atan(rA / rB)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

Comment: @storedprocedure I'm working on a similar application where I get a stream of Lat/Long amd I have to rotate the maps as the vehicle moves. In your code snippet in the comments, could you please clarify what are alpha, beta, gamma?